# AJAX setting variables on a loop with XML Element Sets

Tags: xml, ajax, function, dom, loops

Can you help? AJAX noob!

Im trying to perform a function on different XML elements sets. I need to do the request return the sets and then loop through each set and perform a function on them.

Im trying to define variables by the child elements of the loop and then pass them into the function.

Any toughts?

My JS is

```
function loadXMLDoc()
{
var xmlhttp;
var txt,x,i;
var BC;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    xmlDoc=xmlhttp.responseXML;
    txt="";
    BC = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName("BusinessCard");
//This is the bit i am unsure about?
    for (i=0;i<BC.length;i++)
      {
    var  name = BC[i].getElementsByTagName("NAME").childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var  phone = BC[i].getElementsByTagName("PHONE").childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    var  email = BC[i].getElementsByTagName("EMAIL").childNodes[0].nodeValue;

      }
function(BC, name, phone, email){}

    }
  }
xmlhttp.open("GET","BC.xml",true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

My XML is...

```
<BusinessCard>
    <NAME>Joe Blog</NAME>
    <PHONE>5555656</PHONE>
    <EMAIL>Joe@email.com</EMAILS
</BusinessCard>

<BusinessCard>
    <NAME>Jonh Smith</NAME>
    <PHONE>6555656</PHONE>
    <EMAIL>Jonh@email.com</EMAILS
</BusinessCard> 

<BusinessCard>
    <NAME>Jurgen Voltermies</NAME>
    <PHONE>5325656</PHONE>
    <EMAIL>Voldermort@email.com</EMAILS
</BusinessCard>
```

Any thoughts would be very helpful??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `firstChild.nodeValue` instead of `childNodes[0]`

Example

```
var  name = BC[i].getElementsByTagName("NAME").firstChild.nodeValue;
```